# Alias to pointer (byte*) in C#

Tags: c#, pointers, alias, using

Is it possible to make an alias on unsafe pointer type, i.e. I wanna use following: `using bytePtr = System.Byte*`.

Will .net developers introduce this feature in future versions (alias to pointer and array types)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, it isn't.

And if it *was*, the syntax would have been:

```
using BytePtr = System.Byte*;
```

but again: no, you can't do that. A `using` alias can not be to a pointer.

Also, `byte*` is both shorter and clearer than `BytePtr`, IMO.

Comment: I need in this alias not for the code brevity and clarity, but for the multipurpose code. In my case both for Script# `using byteAr = PixelArray` and for an usual .NET `using byteAr = byte*` or `using byteAr = byte[]`.

Comment: I understand you too. This restriction is sad due to `#if #else #endif` blocks will dirty code.

Answer (score 2):

No, the using aliases are about namespaces and type-names only. You cannot use it for 'derived' types.

For comparison, the following will not compile either:

```
 using NullDate = System.DateTime?;
```

The error (on the '?') is simply `';'` expected.

Answer (score 2):

Not possible. If you insist you could define a wrapper class or struct and get something very close. I wouldn't recommend this however, because it seems to add little value.

Something like this:

```
unsafe struct BytePtr
{
    public BytePtr(byte *value)
    {
        _value = value;
    }

    private byte* _value;

    public byte* Value
    {
        get { return _value; }
    }
}
```